# CloudFlare API v4, no way of enabling cloudflare proxy on dns records

Tags: api, cloud, cloudflare, flare

So I'm working on something in C# that uses the JSON API from CloudFlare to automate the process of adding DNS records. However the website shows a grey cloud that must be clicked to orange to enable their service. I was wondering if there was a way of doing this in C# since I can't see the functionality in their API.

Answer (score 1):

Ah! Found a solution to my problem. CloudFlare don't mention in their API  that you can specify the `proxied` mode to `true` in the JSON data you send in the POST request to create the DNS record.

Comment: @Sendy CloudFlare documentation [here](https://api.cloudflare.com/#dns-records-for-a-zone-create-dns-record) has only 4 fields documented `type`, `name` ,`content` and `ttl`. If you add a field called `proxied` and set that to `true` it will work. Example `{"type":"A","name":"example.com","content":"127.0.0.1","ttl":120,"proxied":true}`

Comment: can't work right now, i have try and have result : Invalid 'proxied' value, must be a boolean

Comment: @Sendy Here is how I constructed my post data: 
`postData = "{\"type\":\"CNAME\",\"name\":\"" + subdomain + "\",\"content\":\"<thecontenthere>\",\"proxied\":true,\"per_page\":20}";`

Comment: My API calls fail when using extra arguments such as proxied? is this still working?

Comment: @Pedro Yes, it is still working. I was getting an error similar to what Sendy mentioned but that only happened in case of using '127.0.0.1'.